# ANARCI Python 2.7.13 - raise child_exception // OSError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, numpy, biopython

I am trying to verify [ANARCI](http://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/ANARCI.php)--an antibody numbering tool--works. It requires Python 2.6+ (running 2.7.13), HMMER3, and Biopython (Numpy in addition to that). I have each of these successfully set up, and when I run one of the example scripts for ANARCI, I get the error described above. Here's the full message from the Python shell:

```
RESTART: /path/anarci_API_example.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/BioAtla-Intern/Downloads/anarci-1.1/Example_scripts_and_sequences/anarci_API_example.py", line 12, in <module>
        results = anarci(sequences, scheme="imgt", output=False)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anarci/anarci.py", line 554, in anarci
        alignments = run_hmmer( sequences, hmm_database=database, hmmerpath=hmmerpath, ncpu=ncpu, bit_score_threshold=bit_score_threshold )
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anarci/anarci.py", line 382, in run_hmmer
        process = Popen( command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE  )
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have been unable to find any help or previous questions for this tool. For those interested in the example file, here it is:

```
# Import the anarci function.
from anarci import anarci

# Format the sequences that we want to number. 
sequences = [("12e8:H","EVQLQQSGAEVVRSGASVKLSCTASGFNIKDYYIHWVKQRPEKGLEWIGWIDPEIGDTEYVPKFQGKATMTADTSSNTAYLQLSSLTSEDTAVYYCNAGHDYDRGRFPYWGQGTLVTVSAAKTTPPSVYPLAP"),
          ("12e8:L","DIVMTQSQKFMSTSVGDRVSITCKASQNVGTAVAWYQQKPGQSPKLMIYSASNRYTGVPDRFTGSGSGTDFTLTISNMQSEDLADYFCQQYSSYPLTFGAGTKLELKRADAAPTVSIFPPSSEQLTSGGASV"),
          ("scfv:A","DIQMTQSPSSLSASVGDRVTITCRTSGNIHNYLTWYQQKPGKAPQLLIYNAKTLADGVPSRFSGSGSGTQFTLTISSLQPEDFANYYCQHFWSLPFTFGQGTKVEIKRTGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSGGGGSEVQLVESGGGLVQPGGSLRLSCAASGFDFSRYDMSWVRQAPGKRLEWVAYISSGGGSTYFPDTVKGRFTISRDNAKNTLYLQMNSLRAEDTAVYYCARQNKKLTWFDYWGQGTLVTVSSHHHHHH"),
          ("lysozyme:A","KVFGRCELAAAMKRHGLDNYRGYSLGNWVCAAKFESNFNTQATNRNTDGSTDYGILQINSRWWCNDGRTPGSRNLCNIPCSALLSSDITASVNCAKKIVSDGNGMNAWVAWRNRCKGTDVQAWIRGCRL")]

# Hand the list of sequences to the anarci function. Number them with the IMGT scheme
results = anarci(sequences, scheme="imgt", output=False)

# Unpack the results. We get three lists
numbering, alignment_details, hit_tables = results

# Each has the same number of elements as the number of sequences submitted
assert len(numbering) == len(alignment_details) == len(hit_tables) == len( sequences )

print 'I am using the anarci function to number and get all the details about the following sequences'
print sequences

print '\n'
# Iterate over the sequences
for i in xrange(len(sequences)):    
    if numbering[i] is None:
        print 'ANARCI did not number', sequences[i][0]
    else:
        print 'ANARCI numbered', sequences[i][0]
        print 'It identified %d domain(s)'%len(numbering[i])

        # Iterate over the domains
        for j in xrange(len(numbering[i])):
            domain_numbering, start_index, end_index = numbering[i][j]
            print 'This is the IMGT numbering for the %d\'th domain:'%j, domain_numbering
            print 'This is the bit of the sequence it corresponds to:', sequences[i][1][start_index:end_index+1]
            print 'These are the details of the alignment:'
         for (key,value) in alignment_details[i][j].iteritems():
              print key, ':', value
            print 'This is the summary of the hits that HMMER found'
         for line in hit_tables[i]:
              print line      
  print '\n','_'*40

print 'Do with this infomation as you wish'

print '\n','*'*40

# Want to just get a quick numbering without caring about the other details?
from anarci import number

seq = "EVQLQQSGAEVVRSGASVKLSCTASGFNIKDYYIHWVKQRPEKGLEWIGWIDPEIGDTEYVPKFQGKATMTADTSSNTAYLQLSSLTSEDTAVYYCNAGHDYDRGRFPYWGQGTLVTVSAAKTTPPSVYPLAP"
numbering, chain_type = number( seq, scheme = 'kabat' )
print 'Alternatively we can simply number the first domain of a sequence with the number function'
print 'I gave it this sequence\n', seq
print 'ANARCI told me it was a', chain_type, 'chain'
print 'This is the first domain\'s Kabat numbering:'
print numbering
```

Any help is appreciated since ANARCI appears to be rather obscure.

Comment: how are you running your script? in which operating system? Windows? Linux?

Comment: OS X 10.11.6, ANARCI isn't supposed to run on Windows. I ran it using the Python shell.

Comment: I tried a little an read the readme.txt, and I think you should try "IMGT" instead "imgt"  in this line: anarci(sequences, scheme="IMGT", output=False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a little the docs, and the error logs, I found out, after installing everything, that the last parameter is the name of the HMMER database, in this case, has one named "ALL", so if you change the name from:

```
results = anarci(sequences, scheme="imgt", output=False)
```

to:

```
results = anarci(sequences, "imgt", "ALL")
```

if after that you still having problems, is because you don't have properly installed HMMER. I installed like this:

in your terminal, type this commands:

```
wget http://eddylab.org/software/hmmer3/3.1b2/hmmer-3.1b2.tar.gz

tar -zxvf hmmer-3.1b2.tar.gz

cd hmmer-3.1b2

./configure && make && sudo make install

cd easel && make check && sudo make install
```

and that's it, for me it's working.

> update

if you have permission problems, you can download the source from here: http://hmmer.org/download.html, then run this commands:

```
cd hmmer-3.1b2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/
make -j 4
make check
make install
```

The output of your script for me returned this list:

```
[((1, ' '), 'E'), ((2, ' '), 'V'), ((3, ' '), 'Q'), ((4, ' '), 'L'),
((5, ' '), 'Q'), ((6, ' '), 'Q'), ((7, ' '), 'S'), ((8, ' '), 'G'),
((9, ' '), 'A'), ((10, ' '), 'E'), ((11, ' '), 'V'), ((12, ' '), 'V'),
((13, ' '), 'R'), ((14, ' '), 'S'), ((15, ' '), 'G'), ((16, ' '), 'A'),
((17, ' '), 'S'), ((18, ' '), 'V'), ((19, ' '), 'K'), ((20, ' '), 'L'),
((21, ' '), 'S'), ((22, ' '), 'C'), ((23, ' '), 'T'), ((24, ' '), 'A'),
((25, ' '), 'S'), ((26, ' '), 'G'), ((27, ' '), 'F'), ((28, ' '), 'N'),
((29, ' '), 'I'), ((30, ' '), 'K'), ((31, ' '), 'D'), ((32, ' '), 'Y'),
((33, ' '), 'Y'), ((34, ' '), 'I'), ((35, ' '), 'H'), ((36, ' '), 'W'),
((37, ' '), 'V'), ((38, ' '), 'K'), ((39, ' '), 'Q'), ((40, ' '), 'R'),
((41, ' '), 'P'), ((42, ' '), 'E'), ((43, ' '), 'K'), ((44, ' '), 'G'),
((45, ' '), 'L'), ((46, ' '), 'E'), ((47, ' '), 'W'), ((48, ' '), 'I'),
((49, ' '), 'G'), ((50, ' '), 'W'), ((51, ' '), 'I'), ((52, ' '), 'D'),
((52, 'A'), 'P'), ((53, ' '), 'E'), ((54, ' '), 'I'), ((55, ' '), 'G'),
((56, ' '), 'D'), ((57, ' '), 'T'), ((58, ' '), 'E'), ((59, ' '), 'Y'),
((60, ' '), 'V'), ((61, ' '), 'P'), ((62, ' '), 'K'), ((63, ' '), 'F'),
((64, ' '), 'Q'), ((65, ' '), 'G'), ((66, ' '), 'K'), ((67, ' '), 'A'), 
((68, ' '), 'T'), ((69, ' '), 'M'), ((70, ' '), 'T'), ((71, ' '), 'A'), 
((72, ' '), 'D'), ((73, ' '), 'T'), ((74, ' '), 'S'), ((75, ' '), 'S'), 
((76, ' '), 'N'), ((77, ' '), 'T'), ((78, ' '), 'A'), ((79, ' '), 'Y'), 
((80, ' '), 'L'), ((81, ' '), 'Q'), ((82, ' '), 'L'), ((82, 'A'), 'S'), 
((82, 'B'), 'S'), ((82, 'C'), 'L'), ((83, ' '), 'T'), ((84, ' '), 'S'), 
((85, ' '), 'E'), ((86, ' '), 'D'), ((87, ' '), 'T'), ((88, ' '), 'A'), 
((89, ' '), 'V'), ((90, ' '), 'Y'), ((91, ' '), 'Y'), ((92, ' '), 'C'), 
((93, ' '), 'N'), ((94, ' '), 'A'), ((95, ' '), 'G'), ((96, ' '), 'H'), 
((97, ' '), 'D'), ((98, ' '), 'Y'), ((99, ' '), 'D'), ((100, ' '), 'R'), 
((100, 'A'), 'G'), ((100, 'B'), 'R'), ((100, 'C'), 'F'), ((101, ' '), 'P'), 
((102, ' '), 'Y'), ((103, ' '), 'W'), ((104, ' '), 'G'), ((105, ' '), 'Q'), 
((106, ' '), 'G'), ((107, ' '), 'T'), ((108, ' '), 'L'), ((109, ' '), 'V'), 
((110, ' '), 'T'), ((111, ' '), 'V'), ((112, ' '), 'S'), ((113, ' '), 'A')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the change to the `results` line, and now nothing happens when I run the code. In your commands for terminal you use `sudo`--is there any way around this? The computer I am working on is not mine and no one knows who set the password or what it is (neither admin password worked).

Comment: @MTJ That's really odd, because I didn't use sudo :/, only to install the python package, ah.. and the HMMER in some point ask me the sudo password also... mmm.. I think that's another problem I don't know how to solve :(, but the main and worse problem was successfully solved :). you can check here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/is-there-a-way-to-stop-having-to-write-sudo-for-every-little-thing-in-linux to find a little more help, but I think you will need the password in some point :(

Comment: You used `sudo` in the terminal commands twice (`...&& sudo make install`). Aren't  those both for HMMER?

Comment: @MTJ yes I'm afraid so, another alternative is to download the binaries from here, uncompress, and open the file named INSTALL, and follow the instructions

Comment: @MTJ I just did it with no sudo need, I made an update to the question for you, let me know if that helps

Comment: Managed to find the `sudo` password and get to `root#` in terminal. Installed HMMER using the first method (the updated version without `sudo` failed).  After it has been installed I still get the same error when running the example file. HMMER isn't installed under `/Library/Frameworks` like Numpy and Biopython are, and instead installs under `/user/local/share/man/man1/`, could the location of the example Python file be causing these issues?

Comment: @MTJ did you try to run from terminal, not by python script, the example given in the website you provided in the link? Let me know if these example return to you what should be

Comment: And now it works. Any reason why this example doesn't work in the Python shell? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MTJ Eeeeeeeey!!! Congratulations! Look, I don't want to lie, I foung a little odd that it doesn't work inside a python shell, I tried the 3 ways, running in the shell `$python program.py` , the other way `ANARCI -i EVQLQQSGAEVV... --scheme chothia` , and finally inside the python shell, run the commands and functions created by you. But, I'm in Linux, I don't know the exact differences between MacOs and Linux, I know they have some things in common. But, finally I'm glad you can achieve the goal :D